# How should I convert numbers in a column to the same format style in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I have two columns Lat and Long in a data frame. I try to convert these strings into float but I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "" at position 61754
```

I've noticed that in my data frame I have numbers written in different styles, even in bold text.
I'm wondering if there is a way to convert the numbers in the same style.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Use `df=df.replace('"','',regex=True)` now convert them to `float`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have this DataFrame:

```
  funny_numbers
0             
1             
2
```

You can try [`.str.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html#pandas-series-str-normalize) to convert the Unicode characters to standard form:

```
df["funny_numbers"] = df["funny_numbers"].str.normalize("NFKD")
df["funny_numbers"] = pd.to_numeric(df["funny_numbers"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  funny_numbers
0             4
1             5
2            76
```